# If magic was real, which sort of particles could explain it?

Tags: magic, physics, alternate-worlds

I was thinking along the lines of how particle physics will change, or need to adapt if we have something like magic being true. I mean there are all different types of magics which are possible like fire, earth, water, air, light, dark, space, time, life, death etc etc. Some of these can be explained if we introduce something like a new particle which can agitate the others, one for photons, but what about the others??

Also will there be any sorts of conservation laws that we can say might hold true in this sort of a world setting. Are there any other theories which might explain these things in a more profound manner ( String theory, super symmetry etc).

Comment: so you want to radically change particle physics while producing a world almost like this one. Even getting matter to be stable will be hard.

Comment: Scintillating Dark Matter Positrons... They exist, I'll prove it - YOU'LL ALL SEE!  )8{D~

Answer (score 1):

Using both magic and physics as tags to a question is inherently in error. Magic is what you use to explain a technology that can't be explained with physics or real science. There is no intersection between the two.

If you want physics, read up on experimental physics, make some assumptions, and go for it. If you want magic, invent new magic.

Nobody thought that Middle Earth was less realistic because Tolkien never explained what particles the One Ring used to change size, or what wavelength the palantir operated on.

Comment: And that is why I am asking this question, well as a reference you can read the light novel Mahouka Koukou no Rettousei, there they assume that magic was actually found out like a physical phenomenon and a particle which explained a few things. But the author never went into the details of the theory, but it gave me the question that if one earnestly tries to decipher magic with the type of physics we know, can it be done. I get your point about magic and science being disjoint, but there are lots of things that can be explained with an elementary particle for magic (i.e. if it was real)

Comment: And really, when you try to over-complicate something that wasn't meant to be scientific, you end up with things like "midichlorians". Like kingledion is saying, it doesn't decrease something's realism by leaving its explanation unexplained.

Answer (score 0):

We have two choices here.

The First: If you define the terms 'magic' and 'physics' really narrow, your question makes no sense (see kingledions answer). Its impossible under this premise to explain magic scientifically, because magic is outside of science in this narrow definition, magic IS DEFINED by being not scientifically explainable.

The Second:  You don't want magic in a narrow sense, but SOFT Sci-Fi.
We have [Mohs Scale of Science Fiction Hardness](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness)
Most Sci-Fi-stories do not use really hard science (and from my personal taste I am very glad they don't).

From an artist point of view, you can use pseudo-scientific explanation like magic. Just think of an awesome effect you want to explain and tell your audience something about your exotic particles.

But why use 'elemental magic' (like in your question) and link it to physics? kingledion said it all.

Of course, you can do this, mixing magic and (soft) sci-fi. But then you are free to create whatever physics you want. Then you yourself are the most qualified person on earth to answer your question.

Want inspiration? [Look no further](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Mohs/ScienceInGenreOnly)